# Footer encroaching the middle section whenever it has less results coming from asp.net repeater

Tags: html, css, asp.net, repeater

[image: This is how I want it to be]It was all working fine, i have no idea what went wrong, i have been comparing the actual theme and my theme with asp.net repeater developed into it to find the mistake but no joy...

Problem is , whenever there are 3 blogs to display, footer appears at footer only but the moment database shows only one blog in the section, footer climbs up in the remaining space.

I think this is how it works, since page dynamically changes itself and footer climbs up..but how do we stop this from happening ?

It looks very ugly, need to have footer at extreme bottom as it used to be when elements are full in the body section, not desirable to see the footer up if section elements are nil

[image: This is how it looks like]

Comment: looks like a css issue (I know, seems such a simple dumb statement) but without seeing more (code, styles, etc) its hard to say. It didn't happen and then started happening? which is the part that climbs up (categories/latest photos?)

Comment: edited now with the new image to show how it actually looks like